folder icons on the desktop are cut in half
As the title suggests, for some reason the file icons are cut in half like this
I have found no solutions on the internet other than this and the solutions failed.
What should i do?
Edit: Thanks to @john i solved it.
i followed this article and deleted the Icon Cache.
Thanks!

That doesn't look cut in half to me, it looks rotated.  Did you change your icons at some point?

how so? also i don't think it is

@squillman I did, but i reverted the change and it didn't fix it

You image is inaccessible.

@harrymc they work for me - which one's broken?

It's accessible now - apparently a momentary glitch that fixed itself.
